# Load file from classpath in wildfly +java

Tags: java, jsp, java-8, jboss, wildfly

I have a simple jsp application.
I am trying to load an xml file which it there in src/xml folder. I am using below code but getting FileNotFound exception. Please let me know how to resolve this issue?

```
Public static void load() {
Document doc = parseDoc(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("/xml/test.xml").getFile())
}
```

This is throwing FileNotFound exception as the path is showing as `/D:/Wildfly/bin/content/aap.war/web-inf/classes/xml/test.xml`

Tried few different ways but didnt work. Please help me

Comment: `getResource(…)` returns a `URL`. There is no guaranty that this is a file in the default filesystem. Most notably, it won’t be when the code is deployed in a jar file. Check whether there’s a version of `parseDoc` accepting a `URL` or an `InputStream` (as you can call `openStream()` on the `URL` or use `getResourceAsStream(…)` in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Generel notes:

Please write **`public`** and not `Public`. "src" is not a good folder to load something. "src" normally contains your source code (aka *.java files) - which is nothing you have access to after the files are compiled and put into your server.

What I would suggest is, that you put your XML file into a jar file. So zip your xml folder and rename it to e.g. "xml.jar". I assume there is one folder xml/test.xml. This jar file you add to your classpath as part of your .ear or .war file. After you deploy this you can access it with:

`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xml/text.xml");`

Also don't directly read it but check for null:

```
InputStream stream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xml/text.xml);
if (stream == null) {
  throw new IllegalStateException("Resource 'xml/text.xml' not found on classpath");
}
//continue
```